# SQL Complexed Join

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list a Purchase Record for a customer by the following tables.

```
Table: Invoice
----------------------

invID | cusID | total
----------------------
1     | 1     | 10.5


Table: Invoice Item
--------------------

invID | prodID
---------------
1     | 1     
1     | 3
```

**Now I want to output as one row Like this: (or in PHP Fetched Row Table)**

```
invID | cusID | prodID | total
-------------------------------
1     | 1     | 1, 3   | 10.5
```

**What have I tried:**

```
SELECT i.*, ii.prodID FROM invoice i, invoiceitem ii WHERE cusID = '1' AND i.invID = ii.invID
Result:

invID | cusID | prodID | total
-------------------------------
1     | 1     | 1      | 10.5
1     | 1     | 3      | 10.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work for you. Haven't tested it so there might be a minor typo somewhere, but the concept should work.

```
SELECT i.invID, i.cusID, GROUP_CONCAT(ii.prodID) `prodID`, i.total
FROM invoice i
INNER JOIN invoiceitem ii ON i.invID = ii.invID
GROUP BY i.invID
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing a [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) over the `prodID`s. You should also use ANSI INNER JOIN syntax, in preference to joining in the WHERE clause. Although MySql doesn't complain, it is also good practice to include all non-aggregated select fields in the GROUP BY, for compliance with other RDBMS's

```
SELECT i.invID, i.cusID, GROUP_CONCAT(ii.prodID) as prodID, i.total
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN invoiceitem ii ON i.invID = ii.invID
WHERE cusID = '1'
GROUP BY i.invID, i.cusID, i.total;
```

Comment: Ansewr Tickmark to Joel, upper triangle (useful answer) to both of you. :)